# How do I add a padding in the Scaffold without using SafeArea?

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I add a responsive padding at the top of my scaffold area,
[Here is the preview of my Scaffold Area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7ee8.png). I want the background there to be transparent or will adjust depending on the users phone theme. However mine is overlapping.
Here is the sample code of my login_page.

login_page.dart

```
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextWidget(
              descriptionText: "Sign In!",
              selectedFontColor: ColourPalette.primaryColor,
              selectedFontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
              selectedFontSize: 25),
          SignInButton(
            Buttons.google,
            text: "Sign up with Google",
            onPressed: () {
              AuthServices().signInWithGoogle();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of wrapping the Scaffold with Safearea, wrap the widget inside the body with Safearea it gives you the same result but the UI will respond according to the theme.

```
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(child:Column(
        children: [
          TextWidget(
              descriptionText: "Sign In!",
              selectedFontColor: ColourPalette.primaryColor,
              selectedFontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
              selectedFontSize: 25),
          SignInButton(
            Buttons.google,
            text: "Sign up with Google",
            onPressed: () {
              AuthServices().signInWithGoogle();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use **SafeArea** and still get the mobile theme color at the top of the screen

you can put a SizedBox in the starting of the column with a height of the top padding

like this:

```
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {


 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
      ),
          TextWidget(
              descriptionText: "Sign In!",
              selectedFontColor: ColourPalette.primaryColor,
              selectedFontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
              selectedFontSize: 25),
          SignInButton(
            Buttons.google,
            text: "Sign up with Google",
            onPressed: () {
              AuthServices().signInWithGoogle();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give color to safe area, you can do it like this:

```
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  const TestScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
              ),
              TextWidget(
                  descriptionText: "Sign In!",
                  selectedFontColor: ColourPalette.primaryColor,
                  selectedFontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  selectedFontSize: 25),
              SignInButton(
                Buttons.google,
                text: "Sign up with Google",
                onPressed: () {
                  AuthServices().signInWithGoogle();
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```